# Ruby class ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, initialization, rake

I was trying to implement progress bar for a rake task , i grab the code for progress bar from the below website

https://coderwall.com/p/ijr6jq/rake-progress-bar

progress_bar.rb

```
 class ProgressBar

  def initialize(total)
    @total   = total
    @counter = 1
  end

  def increment
    complete = sprintf("%#.2f%", ((@counter.to_f / @total.to_f) * 100))
    print "\r\e[0K#{@counter}/#{@total} (#{complete})"
    @counter += 1
  end

end
```

progress_bar_test.rake

```
namespace :progress_bar_test do

  desc "Testing progress bar"

  task :start => :environment do
      items = (1..1000).to_a
      progress_bar = ProgressBar.new(items.size)
      items.each do |item|
        item.to_s ## Call a real method here, example: `item.update(foo: 'bar')`
        progress_bar.increment
      end
  end
end
```

When i run the rake task i got the following error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Full error message

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
/home/user/rails_app/lib/tasks/progress_bar_test.rake:8:in `initialize'
/home/user/rails_app/lib/tasks/progress_bar_test.rake:8:in `new'
/home/user/rails_app/lib/tasks/progress_bar_test.rake:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => progress_bar_test:start
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

> But when i initialize the same class in IRB i did not face any problem

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post more of error message ?

Comment: @phoenix updated the question with full error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have the [progress_bar](https://github.com/paul/progress_bar) or [ruby-progressbar](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar) gem installed on your system.

When you do `require 'progress_bar'`, it's loading the gem and not your local class. You could try doing `require_relative 'progress_bar'`, or renaming your class (and/or it's file name) so that it loads your local file instead of the gem.

Comment: You likely have the [`progress_bar` gem](https://github.com/paul/progress_bar) installed on your system. When you do `require 'progress_bar'`, it's loading the gem and not your local class. You could try doing `require_relative 'progress_bar'`, or renaming your class (and/or it's file name) so that it loads your local file instead of the gem.

Comment: Ruy Diaz, you have an eagle eye man LOL, yes indeed i have installed a gem Ruby-progressbar this gem has a class ProgressBar as well, that is the problem, oh man you saved my day, Thanks